# Changing Dynamic Arrays lengths?

Tags: c++, class, object, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Lets say that I own a repair shop and I want to add a vehicle to my database each time a new customer comes to my shop. Assuming that I have a car class that asks for all the necessary information. Is is possible to create a dynamic array of this object that is constantly adding or subtracting the amount of customer cars that come into the shop, or is this more improbable?

Ex.

```
    using namespace std; //I know its not a good idea to use, prof wants us too.

    class Car{
         Car(){
         //get user data
         }
    };

    int main () {

          int choice;
          static int counter = 0;
          Car *car = new Car[Counter];

          cout << "Would you like to add a vehicle to the our database(yes/no): ";
          cin >> choice;
                if (choice == "yes") {
                    car[counter].Car::Car();
                    counter++;
                }
```

Comment: If you want to create a dynamic array, you should use built in container `std::vector` as `std::vector<Car>` but remember to include `#include <vector>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `vector` from the **Standard Template Library**:

```
#include <vector>

...
vector<Car> car;
...
if (choice == "yes") {
    car.push_back(Car{});
}
```

You won't need `counter` variable on your `main` function, since you can use
the method `size`, which returns the number of elements inside the vector.

e.g.

```
car.size();
```

For removing items, use the method `pop_back` or the method `erase`

e.g.

```
car.pop_back();  // Remove last element from car vector
car.erase(3); // Remove the 4th element from car vector
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with raw dynamic arrays, but it is *very* complicated as you are going to have to manually manage your memory and deal with a lot of pointer arithmetic. To simplify this process, the STL contains [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which represents an dynamic array that can easily be changed in size. For example:

```
std::vector<Car> car;

cout << "Would you like to add a vehicle to the our database(yes/no): ";
cin >> choice;

if (choice == "yes") {
    car.push_back(Car{}); // No indices required; Just add a new car to the end
    counter++; // You might not even need this, 
               // as there is std::vector::size for that
}
```

Similarly, to remove a `Car`, you can use `std::vector::pop_back` which can be called in the same way as `std::vector::push_back`.

Comment: Why you're passing `counter` to car vector constructor?

Comment: @aaamourao Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Letting a dynamically allocated array grow and shrink is possible, but tricky.
Fortunately, standard library provides containers (e.g. `std::vector`) for exactly this issue:

```
struct Car{
    Car(string _type) : type(_type) { };
    string type;
};

int main () {

    std::vector<Car> cars;
    while(1) {
        string input;
        cout << "Enter the type of a new car (or 'exit'):" << endl;
        if (!(cin >> input) || input=="exit") {
            break;
        }
        cout << "added." << endl;
        cars.emplace_back(input);
    }

    cout << "you have entered " << cars.size() << " car(s):" << endl;
    for(auto car : cars) {
        cout << car.type << endl;
    }

}
```